How to include always-excluded build folder in IntelliJ IDEA
I have setup the "build" folder in IDEA to be a "source" type (We have a collection of build scripts there). As seen here in the screenshot.
Regardless of that setting, the build folder is still excluded, with all its navigation-ability/searchability downsides.
How can I get this folder back into
